# Can Kotlin scope functions be used to write test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

Can a scope function be used instead of calling functions individually on the assertThat(...)

```kotlin
    fun cashCardSerializationTest() {
        val cashCard = CashCard(99L, 123.45)

        assertThat(json.write(cashCard)).isStrictlyEqualToJson("expected.json")
        assertThat(json.write(cashCard)).hasJsonPathNumberValue("@.id")
        assertThat(json.write(cashCard)).extractingJsonPathNumberValue("@.id")
    }
```

Comment: I tried the with() but don't know if it's the correct function.

Comment: What do you mean by the "correct" function? Did it work?

Comment: It worked but is it the right function?

Comment: What would make it a wrong function? The scope functions are very flexible and they are interchangeable for some purposes.